# Add to PATH for later use with os.system or subprocess.Popen in the same script

Tags: python, windows, path, subprocess, python-os

Let's say `"D:\Temp\Subfolder\mytest.exe"` is not in the PATH yet. I tried:

```
import os, sys, subprocess
sys.path.append("D:\Temp\Subfolder")           # 1
os.environ['PATH'] += "D:\Temp\Subfolder"      # 2
```

but in both cases, this fails:

```
os.system('mytest')
subprocess.Popen('mytest')
```

**Question: how to set the PATH for the currently running process, such that `os.system` and `subprocess.Popen` (or those commands called by *imported libraries*, this is my use case) don't fail?**

PS: I'm looking for a solution without having to manually edit environment variables with Windows' GUI: *Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables > ...*

Comment: I am not sure about the sys.path.append but while setting and appending 'mytest' dir to the PATH env, we need to use [os.pathsep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pathsep). Any error log might help as well to conclude what's the problem here.

Comment: Could you give an example command to do that @Jay? I'm not sure how it would help here.

Comment: `os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + "D:\Temp\Subfolder" `. This should let the subprocess execute `mytest`. @Basj

Comment: Oh that's right @Jay, I thought it was a *list*, in fact `os.environ['PATH']` is a string! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Jay in a comment, the solution is to do:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + r"D:\Temp\Subfolder"
```

(this assumes that the environment variable `PATH` already exists; it could be useful to check this before)

Indeed, `os.environ['PATH']` is a string and not a list (this is what I initially thought).

Then, both:

```
os.system('mytest')
subprocess.Popen('mytest')
```

work.

---

Note: None of these work:

```
sys.path.append(os.pathsep + "D:\Temp\Subfolder")
sys.path.append("D:\Temp\Subfolder")
```

Comment: `"D:\Temp\Subfolder"` should be a raw string literal in general, e.g. `folder = r"D:\Temp\Subfolder"`. It shouldn't assume that `PATH` exists. If `'PATH' is not in os.environ` then set `os.environ['PATH'] = folder`. Else set `os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'].rstrip(os.pathsep) + os.pathsep + folder`. To pass an updated module path (i.e. `sys.path`) to a child Python process, you can follow the exact same pattern with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.